# C extension not loaded for Word2Vec

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I re-install the gensim pkg and Cython but it continusly show this warning,
Does anybody know about this?
I am using Python 3.6,PyCharm Linux Mint.

UserWarning: C extension not loaded for Word2Vec, training will be slow. Install a C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.
  warnings.warn("C extension not loaded for Word2Vec, training will be slow. "

And it also show this line when I create or load model.
Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used

Answer (score 4):

There is some problem with the some underlying packages not being up to date. [Here](http://The%20problem%20is%20to%20do%20with%20the%20some%20underlying%20packages%20not%20being%20up%20to%20date.) I found the answer which work for me, which is in short:

Uninstall Gensim

```
sudo pip3 uninstall gensim
```

Install python3-dev build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev build-essential
```

Re-Install Gensim

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade gensim
```

Notes:

Instructions above are for systems where pip and apt-get are used to manage packages
pip3 is the python3 version of pip

Comment: The key is the `python3-dev` (or in Py2, just `python-dev`) and `build-essential` packages. If they are present when gensim is installed, the optimized code included with the package can be compiled. (`cython` isn't actually necessary unless you're further customizing that code.)

Comment: How to solve this problem in a windows environment with Python 3 on it?

Comment: what is the speed difference with and without?

Comment: Like @AkilaAmarasinghe, I wanted to find a solution on Windows. This resolved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986444/5433896.