# Gensim: "C extension not loaded, training will be slow."

Tags: pip, word2vec, gensim, opensuse, suse

I am running gensim on Linux Suse. I can start my python program but on startup I get:

> C extension not loaded, training will be slow. Install a C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.

GCC is installed. Does anyone know what I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

**Python 3.x**

```
$ pip3 uninstall gensim    
$ apt-get install python3-dev build-essential      
$ pip3 install --upgrade gensim
```

**Python 2.x**

```
$ pip uninstall gensim    
$ apt-get install python-dev build-essential      
$ pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem is that on Suse, I do not have apt-get (like on Ubuntu). Do you know what I have to do on Suse specifically? I assume I need to use zypper (which works for python3-dev but not for build-essential).

Comment: @Janothan Oh, sorry, I missed that. Try `zypper install -t pattern devel_basis`

Comment: Thanks! The problem is on that in Windows. Well, `apt-get is not recognized as an internal or external command`? Please suggest how to do this on windows specifically with python 3.7?

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499558/c-extension-not-loaded-for-word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499558/c-extension-not-loaded-for-word2vec)

Comment: Like @MishraS, I wanted to find a solution on Windows. This resolved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986444/5433896.