# How to fix 'C extension not loaded, training will be slow. Install a C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, gensim, word2vec

I'm using the library node2vec, which is based on gensim word2vec model to encode nodes in an embedding space, but when i want to fit the word2vec object I get this warning:

> C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py:743:
>   UserWarning: C extension not loaded, training will be slow. Install a
>   C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.

Can any one help me to fix this issue please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before posting, please search to see if your question has already been asked. In this case, your answer might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306710/gensim-c-extension-not-loaded-training-will-be-slow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gensim: "C extension not loaded, training will be slow."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306710/gensim-c-extension-not-loaded-training-will-be-slow)

Comment: @SmrtGrunt, the duplicate might not be helpful here, because this is on a windows machine and the duplicate gives instructions for ubuntu.

Comment: It would be helpful to include in your question how you installed gensim. Did you use pip or conda?

Comment: @cel i used pip install gensim, and i upgrade to the latest version 3.7.2 but still ...

Comment: @Aziziilias, I would recommend uninstalling with pip and reinstalling with `conda install gensim` - packages which rely on extension modules can sometimes be tricky to get to work on windows.

Comment: @cel  with conda install gensim command i installed the 3.4.0 which works very well, thank you dude

Answer (score 9):

gensim relies on extension modules that need to be compiled. Both defaults and the conda-forge channel provide prebuilt versions that will work out of the box.

```
conda install gensim
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge gensim
```

are probably the easiest way to get gensim to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, degrading back to Gensim version 3.7.1 from 3.7.3 worked.

Answer (score 1):

anaconda prompt
conda update conda-build

==
windows 7 (32bit)
python 3.7.3
conda-build 3.18.5
gensim 3.4.0

Comment: Actually this worked in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue for a long time when I was running W2V Models which requires 'gensim'.
First of all I've installed Anaconda Navigator and then installed required packages using pip.
I've installed gensim manually using pip in cmd. When I run the W2V model, it took 40 min to train and give the result, which made me annoying and wasted a lot of time.

This problem got solved now. I just did what the warning showed. I've uninstalled gensim from my computer. Prior to that I've already created a system path of mingw-w64 in the environment variable which is an environment for c,c++ etc., programs. Later, I've reinstalled gensim using 'pip install gensim'.

Now the program is running within seconds which made a drastic change in the execution time.

Hope this helps...